# Accessing a blob storage

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook, azure-blob-storage

How do I access a file in my Azure blob storage using my Jupyter Notebook in my Azure container?

import pyspark
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('i put the file path in my blob storage.csv')

Comment: Try these steps found in this [page](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/educator-developer-blog/using-external-data-with-azure-jupyter-notebooks/ba-p/379007)

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, the below code was working fine.

```
import  pandas  as  pd

pd.read_csv('https://<STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME>.blob.core.windows.net/<CONTAINER_NAME>/<BLOB_NAME>')
```

Make sure you are installing pandas using

```
pip install pandas
```

**RESULTS:**

[image]

Alternatively, this would work same as above using `BlockBlobService` by downloading the blob locally.

```
import pandas as pd
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

ACCOUNT_NAME= "<YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME>"
ACCOUNT_KEY= "<YOUR_ACCOUNT_KEY>"
CONTAINER_NAME= "<YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME>"
BLOBNAME= "<BLOB_NAME>"

blob_service = BlockBlobService(ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_KEY)

blob_service.get_blob_to_path(CONTAINER_NAME,BLOBNAME,BLOBNAME)
df = pd.read_csv('<PATH_OF_THE_DOWNLOADED_BLOB>'+BLOBNAME)
print(df)
```

**RESULTS:**

[image]